# Cant connect to mqtt musquitto on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

When I publish and subscribe at localhost its work fine.

When I try from my PC at home I just can't connect to the broker.

open TCP port in/out at security group - 1883 8883 8080
open the ports also at my ec2 instance firewall...

what is the problem? I use the public DNS by amazon as I think I should...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the doc on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: But there is no code to attach.

Comment: The mosquitto logs and it's config file, some description of the client you are using to connect?

Comment: I need to config something more?

Comment: I trying​ from mqtt spy . And from Android app.. from both I succeed to connect to test broker. But when I try to my ec2 instance broker it feild

Comment: Someone succeed to connect mosquitto broker at ec2 instance from outside AWS?

Answer (score 0):

This is an exercise at diagnosing network problems:

1) netstat -a -n | grep 1883

will tell you whether your broker is configured correctly

2) wireshark packet capture will tell you whether your system is receiving packets at the specific port

You will not get an answer until you  at least do those.